# Security schemes regularly in use on cloud

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, cloud-computing

I've been looking into how connections are managed in the cloud, in order to better understand the threats users and their deployments may face.

The most important and common ones in use seem to be either SSH, to connect directly to an instance, or between two instances, or something using key managers to look after multiple connections using PKI, something like Kerberos for instance.

Are there any other important ones I've missed? I've been looking but haven't found anything which lists specific schemes and this is what I've come up with.

Comment: What kind of connections, and from which systems?  From a trusted system outside the cloud (your desk) to inside the cloud?  Within the same cloud provider?  Between different cloud providers?  From an untrusted system outside the cloud (app or Web user) to the cloud?

Comment: In the cloud, you will find all security schemes that are used outside the cloud. It has different risks, but it is not different in real terms to anything else you do on a network.

Comment: In answer to both comments, I understand that the connections in the cloud are the same as outside. What I was really wondering was, in all cases of cloud use (in answer to Anti-weak passwords), what the most common forms of encrypted connections might be. Other than using secure channels and key management to manage multiple connections. It is difficult to find a source explaining these.